# How to put text behind an image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am new to CSS and I want to put text "MOUNTAINS" behind the mountain in the background image. Like the below image.

[Home section image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UzVz.png)

This is the existing code

```css
#home{    
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

#home-img{
    background: url("../img/home/1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;       
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}

#home-content{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 124px;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
}

#home-content #first-title{
    color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
}

#home-content #second-title{
    color: rgb(65, 79, 107);
}

#home-content h1{
    font-size: 115px;
    margin-left: -25%;
    margin-top: -8%;
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Background Image -->
            <div id="home-img" class="col-md-12">

            </div>
            <!-- Home Content -->
            <div id="home-content">
                <h1 id="first-title">LOSANGELES</h1>
                <h1 id="second-title">MOUNTAINS</h1>
            </div>
</section>
```

I am stuck with this. So can CSS expert help me to do this? Thank you

Comment: Do you have 2 image or only one?

Comment: only one image in the background

Comment: With one image what doi you want to achieve is impossible. You need oneimage for the mountains and one image for the background

Answer (score 2):

Hi please have a look to the snippet.

```
**z-index** and **position** are important key factors for this case
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/53594/blue-clouds-day-fluffy-53594.jpeg);">
 <div style="background-image: url(https://gallery.yopriceville.com/var/resizes/Free-Clipart-Pictures/Grass-Grounds-Coverings-PNG-Clipart/Green_Grass_PNG_Clip_Art_Image.png?m=1532246688);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 100vh; width: 100%; background-size: contain;
    background-position: bottom; z-index: 8; position: relative;">
 </div>
 <h1 style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; font-size: 40vh; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); left: 50%; top: 25%; text-align: center;">Hello<br>Mountain </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code. Try this and replace the files here with yours:

```css
.box{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block; /* Make the width of box same as image */
    }
    .box .text{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;        
        text-align: center;
        top: 35%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
        color: #000; /*Set your own colour*/
        width: 60%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example of Text Block Over Image</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="box">
     <img src="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/examples/images/kites.jpg" alt="Flying Kites">
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Flying Kites</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**I hope it helps.**

Comment: He want the text behind the mountains. this example doesn't give a solution